# Tarefas programadas em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho um banco de dados com informações sobre livros e empréstimos dos mesmos, quando o tempo que o livro pode ficar emprestado vence então o sistema deve mudar o status do registro de empréstimo. Pensei em fazer isso como uma tarefa programada, há alguma forma de realizar essa tarefa utilizando somente PHP (sem tarefas agendadas do windows ou equivalente no linux)?

Comment: Qual o banco de dados?

Comment: Estou usando MySQL

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode criar [eventos](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) no próprio MySQL, para isso será necessário habilitar o opção `event_scheduler=1` no `My.ini`, exemplo:

```
/*Executa de hora em hora*/
CREATE EVENT e_hourly_book
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY 1 HOUR
COMMENT 'Altera o Status dos livros'
DO
  UPDATE livro SET ...;
```

Comment: Muito BOM! vou favoritar.