# PHP - Pegar um valor e modificar o dia da data

Tags: php, data, php-5, data-manipulation

Estou com uma duvida sobre manipulação de data. Preciso pegar um valor (dado pelo usuario) e transformar este valor em dia do mês.

**Exemplo :**

```
$Valor_Usuario = 30;
$Data = 12/10/2018;
$Resultado = 30/10/2018;
```

O que estou buscando fazer é, uma rotina de gastos, então o usuario me informa um dia fixo de gasto, (Todo dia 30 irei gastar R$50) e o sistema todo dia 30 irá subtrair R$50 da conta. O que me gera outra duvida...

Depois da manipulação da data como fazer esse checking da data? (Se hoje é dia 30 ou não // Para saber quando subtrair os R$ 50)

**RESOLVIDO**

*Manipulação da data:*

```
$data = explode("-",date('d-m-Y')); //coloquei a data em array
$data[0] = 31; //mudei "manualmente" o array do dia ($data[0])
$nova = implode("-", $data); //juntei os arrays novamente
NA TELA = 31-12-2018
$check = date("t", strtotime('m-Y')); //Peguei o dia max do mes Ex:28,29...
$conv = $data[0] < $check ? $data[0]:$check; //Se a DT do usuario for < DT do mes = DT do usuario SENAO DT do mes
```

*Agendamento De Tarefas*

- Utilizei o **TaskScheduler** do windows.
- Pedi para o Task abrir todo dia o PHP.exe. //tem que abrir o php.exe pq senao o  task abrirá a pagina e no meu caso eu queria executar o script
- E como parametro abrir o diretorio do meu script (c:xampp\htdocs\teste\teste.php).

Comment: Bem vindo ao StackOverflow em Português. Editei sua pergunta para remover as saudações pois costumamos manter o texto o mais limpo possível para focar na sua dúvida sobre programação. Caso tenha interesse em visitar uma parte do site que não é voltado para tirar dúvidas pode conhecer o [chat]. Se tiver dúvidas quanto ao funcionamento, regras e procedimentos do site visite o [meta] :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um simples `date()` deve resolver seu problema:

```
$hoje = date("d/m/Y");
$diaDoUsuario = 30;
$proximaData = $diaDoUsuario."/".date("m/Y");

if($proximaData == $hoje){
    echo "SIM! É hoje que vou subtrair o valor!";
}
```

Porém, você pode precisar saber se o dia que ele escolheu existe no mês. Por exemplo, no mês de fevereiro o dia máximo pode ser em 28 ou 29. Então eu faria assim:

```
$hoje = date("d/m/Y");
$diaDoUsuario = 30;
// PEGA O DIA MÁXIMO DO MÊS
$diaMaximo = date("t", strtotime(date("Y-m")));
// SE O DIA DO USUÁRIO FOR MAIOR QUE O DIA MÁXIMO DO MÊS, ENTÃO O DIA MÁXIMO SERÁ ESCOLHIDO, SE NÃO, DIA DO USUÁRIO
$diaCorreto = $diaDoUsuario > $diaMaximo ? $diaMaximo : $diaDoUsuario;

$proximaData = $diaCorreto."/".date("m/Y");

if($proximaData == $hoje){
    echo "SIM! É hoje que vou subtrair o valor!";
}
```

Para agendar uma tarefa no linux para executar esse script diariamente, você pode usar o crontab.

Tem duas publicações muito boas aqui:

[Como agendar uma tarefa recorrente no linux?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2818/como-agendar-uma-tarefa-recorrente-no-linux/2827#2827)

[Configurar Cronjob para executar de 5 em 5 minutos, quando estiver dentre 5 a 20 horas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/124518/configurar-cronjob-para-executar-de-5-em-5-minutos-quando-estiver-dentre-5-a-20)

Também há a possibilidade de fazer execuções de eventos direto no banco de dados. Tem uma ótima publicação sobre isso aqui:

[Tarefas programadas em PHP](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/205096/tarefas-programadas-em-php) (a resposta está em mysql)

Comment: Fala Andrei !! Então cara isso resolve meu problema com a manipulação da data, porem o IF não resolve meu problema de agendamento, porque eu preciso que esse codigo rode todo os dias, (não digo o dia inteiro, mas em um horario especifico) para validar se vai subtrair o valor ou não

Comment: Para isso você precisa criar um Crontab. Que irá rodar esse script todos os dias e fazer a verificação...

Comment: @PedroTerencio-GamerArtist veja: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2818/como-agendar-uma-tarefa-recorrente-no-linux/2827#2827

Comment: Legal, mas no meu caso, estou rodando em um localhost, e meu SO é um windows 10, o crontab funcionaria da mesma forma ?

Comment: @PedroTerencio-GamerArtist você está usando um xampp ou wampp certo?

Comment: Isso, utilizando xampp, com PHP5

Comment: Sensacional, vou testar aqui, e se der tudo certo, edito o post com a solução

Comment: @PedroTerencio-GamerArtist se minha resposta estiver certa, por favor qualifique-a. Abraço!